# What runs in PowerShell when I type "alias"?

Tags: powershell

What runs in PowerShell when I run the "alias" command?

Is it an alias? A function? It appears that "alias" is itself an alias to the get-alias command. Yet alias itself does not show up in the list returned by get-alias. Is it being stripped out?

(This is out of curiosity, I'm not planning on re-aliasing "alias" or anything crazy.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In powershell, if a command does not immediately match something in the command search path, it will prepend it with "get-" and try again. So when you type "alias," powershell will retry with "get-alias" if the former is not matched against a command.

-Oisin

Comment: Nice to know. Any link to a help topic to back that up? I know it works, but an official explanation might be even better.

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell 2, you'll get a list of defined aliases. It tells, for exemple, that `gal` is an alias to `get-alias`.

Running `Get-Help alias | more` brings this:

> PS C:\Users\Fernando> Get-Help alias |
>   more
>
> PROVIDER NAME
>       Alias
>
> DRIVES
>       Alias:
>
> SYNOPSIS
>       Provides access to the Windows PowerShell aliases and the values that
>   they represent.
>
> DESCRIPTION
>       The Windows PowerShell Alias provider lets you get, add, change,
>   clear, and delete aliases in Windows
>   PowerShell.
>
> ```
> An alias is an alternate name for a cmdlet, function, or executable
> ```
>
> file. Windows PowerShell includes a
>   set of buil
>       t-in aliases. And, you can add your own aliases to the current
>   session and to your Windows PowerShell
>   profile.
>
> ```
> The Alias provider is a flat namespace that contains only the alias
> ```
>
> objects. The aliases have no child
>   items.
>
> ```
> Each alias is an instance of the System.Management.Automation.AliasInfo
> ```
>
> class.
>
> ```
> The Alias provider exposes its data store in the Alias: drive. To
> ```
>
> work with aliases, you can change your
>   location t
>       o the Alias: drive by using the following command:
>
> ```
>     set-location alias:
>
> Or, you can work from any other Windows PowerShell drive. To reference
> ```
>
> an alias from another location, use
>   the Alia
>       s: drive name in the path.
>
> ```
> Windows PowerShell includes a set of cmdlets that are designed to view
> ```
>
> and to change aliases:
>
> ```
>     Export-Alias
>     Get-Alias
>     Import-Alias
>     New-Alias
>     Set-Alias
>
> When you use these cmdlets, you do not need to specify the Alias: drive
> ```
>
> in the name.
>
> ```
> The Alias provider supports all the cmdlets that have the Item noun
> ```
>
> except for the Invoke-Item cmdlet.
>   And, it supp
>       orts the Get-Content and Set-Content cmdlets. The Alias
>   provider does not support the cmdlets
>   that have the ItemPro
>       perty noun. And, the Alias provider does not support the Filter
>   parameter in any cmdlet.
>
> ```
> All changes to the aliases affect the current session only. To save the
> ```
>
> changes, add the changes to the
>   Windows Pow
>       erShell profile. Or, use the Export-Alias and Import-Alias cmdlets.